# Display search button on the right of input text

Tags: html

I want to display the search button on the right of input text but it shows up below it. How can I show it on the right? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1tj9b755/).

```
<div class="row">
              <div class="page-header col-md-12">
                <h1 class="text-center">Search Teachers</h1>
              </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:80px;">
        <!--
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-4  col-xs-12">
        <div class="ui-widget">
          <label for="tags">Class: </label>
          <input id="class">
        </div>
        </div>
        -->
        <form class="form-signin" id="Form1" action="search.php" method="post"> 

        <div class=" col-xs-12" style="float:left;display:inline;">
        <div class="ui-widget">
          <label for="city">City: </label>
          <input type="text" id="city"  name="city">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-default"  type="submit">Search</button> 
        </div>
        </form>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the button actually will not be inside the input field

you can just add `margin-right:-10px` fro the search button

find clean and working fiddel :[here](http://jsfiddle.net/1tj9b755/1/)

Comment: I did not understood it. I want the button to show next to the input field.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="page-header col-md-12">
    <h1 class="text-center">Search Teachers</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="margin-top:80px;">
     <!--
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-4  col-xs-12">
        <div class="ui-widget">
          <label for="tags">Class: </label>
          <input id="class">
        </div>
        </div>
    -->
    <form class="form-signin" id="Form1" action="search.php" method="post"> 

    <div class=" col-xs-12" style="float:left;display:inline;">
    <div class="ui-widget" style="float:left; margin-right: 10px">
      <label for="city">City: </label>
      <input type="text" id="city"  name="city">
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-default"  type="submit">Search</button> 
    </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

Add **style="float:left; margin-right: 10px"**

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It would help people if you expained why your answer works (and where to add the style).